# Allowing additional URL segment

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am working on with a site without framework and using traditional PHP. I'm having problem with adding new parameters to the URL it is throwing 404 not found.

for example http://dev.test.com/article/ is working and directed to index.php under article directory. but I want to add new parameter to the url for example.

http://dev.test.com/article/article-title/article-id

can you guys please help me how to do this? do i need to add something to htaccess or I can add some few php lines to the code?

Hope someone can help me thanks.

Comment: You want to load http://dev.test.com/article/index.php and use article-title/article-id as parameter?

Comment: Exactly. Do you have any idea how can I do this?

Comment: Try a redirect match in your .htaccess: `RedirectMatch "^.*$" "http://dev.test.com/article/"`

Comment: Hi @ThomasSablik it doesn't work it says page "This page isn’t working". I tried adding it in the main htaccess I also tried creating new htaccess inside article folder. same result.

Comment: [Here](https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/215747748-How-can-I-redirect-and-rewrite-my-URLs-with-an-htaccess-file-) you can read about redirects. An easy way should be `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` `RewriteRule . /article/index.php [L]`. Remember to enable rewrites with `RewriteEngine On`

Comment: [Here](https://gist.github.com/RaVbaker/2254618) is a good instruction for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `.htaccess` file in the folder `article` and insert:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

First line enables rewriting. Second line checks, if requested url is a directory. Third line checks, if requested line is a file. Fourth line redirects if requested url is neither file nor directory.

This configuration redirects all requests for files and folders that do not exist to `index.php`.

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks Sir. :D